# How to add StackNavigator for TabNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I have a app that need both StackNavigator and TabNavigator. The logic is:

```
const App = StackNavigator({
    Welcome: {
        screen: Welcome
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Register
    },
    Auth: {
        screen: Auth
    },
    Home: {
        screen: Main
    },
});

const Main = TabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Dash: { screen: Dash},
  Myself: { screen: Myself},
  });

const Pages = StackNavigator({
    Share: { screen: Share},
    About: { screen: About},
    Service: {screen: Service}
});
```

I can correctly handle how to jump from `App` to `App`, but in the TabNavigator in screen `Myself` I want to jump to the StackNavigator `Pages`, if I add it directly to `Main`, it doesn't work.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something similar to how you put a TabNavigator inside of a StackNavigator with `Main`. You can also put a StackNavigator inside of a TabNavigator.
In this case, you want to use your `Pages` navigator as the `MySelf` route on your `Main` TabNavigator, and instead of having a page `MySelf` on the TabNavigator route, put `MySelf` as the initial route on the `Pages` StackNavigator.

It will look like something like this:

```
...
const Pages = StackNavigator({
  Index: { screen: MySelf },
  Share: { screen: Share },
  About: { screen: About },
  Service: { screen: Service },
}); 

const Main = TabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Dash: { screen: Dash},
  Myself: { screen: Pages},
});
```